# redhawksdr build on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm trying to install redhawksdr on ubuntu 16.10. I have installed dependencies according to docomentation provided by redhawk, but I'm getting error while installing core frameworks. Please help to resolve the issue.
Thanks
Log is given below

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/shahzad/f/src/control/framework'
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-CorbaGC.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-File_impl.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-FileManager_impl.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-FileSystem_impl.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-GCThread.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-helperFunctions.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-POACreator.lo
  CXX      libossiedomain_la-prop_utils.lo
  CXXLD    libossiedomain.la
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
  CXX      nodeBooter-nodebooter.o
nodebooter.cpp: In function ‘void initializeDaemon(const string&, const string&, const string&)’:
nodebooter.cpp:400:37: warning: ignoring return value of ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     freopen("/dev/null", "r", stdin);
                                     ^
nodebooter.cpp:401:38: warning: ignoring return value of ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
                                      ^
nodebooter.cpp:402:38: warning: ignoring return value of ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
                                      ^
  CXXLD    nodeBooter
../../base/framework/.libs/libossiecf.a(libossiecf_la-loghelpers.o): In function `ossie::logging::Configure(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&, std::string&)':
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/loghelpers.cpp:1114: undefined reference to `log4cxx::xml::DOMConfigurator::configure(std::string const&)'
../../base/framework/.libs/libossiecf.a(libossiecf_la-rh_logger.o): In function `rh_logger::L4Logger::handleLogEvent(boost::shared_ptr<rh_logger::Level> const&, std::string const&)':
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:836: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::operator<<(std::string const&)'
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:836: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str(log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&)'
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:836: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::string const&) const'
../../base/framework/.libs/libossiecf.a(libossiecf_la-rh_logger.o): In function `rh_logger::L4Logger::handleLogEvent(boost::shared_ptr<rh_logger::Level> const&, std::string const&, rh_logger::spi::LocationInfo const&)':
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:851: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::operator<<(std::string const&)'
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:851: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str(log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&)'
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:851: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::string const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
../../base/framework/.libs/libossiecf.a(libossiecf_la-rh_logger.o): In function `rh_logger::L4Logger::L4Logger(std::string const&)':
/home/shahzad/f/src/base/framework/logging/rh_logger.cpp:748: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:601: recipe for target 'nodeBooter' failed
make[2]: *** [nodeBooter] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/shahzad/f/src/control/framework'
Makefile:482: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shahzad/f/src/control'
Makefile:600: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of redhawk are you trying to build? The latest release is 2.0.3 which I also cannot build on Ubuntu 16.10 but for different reasons. Yours looks like a linker error while my issue is a compile issue.

Comment: After trying to build redhawk 2.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 my advice is to review this SO post as all of the patches I am making are in line with this original post and are due to differences in gcc version between Centos6 and Ubuntu 16.10 / fedora 24. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571741/building-redhawk-cf-from-source-on-fedora24

Comment: I'm trying to build redhawk 2.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 and it gives error when file size of redhawk-src-2.0.3 reaches to 210 Mb. Does this version works on 14.04? Or please tell me some working platform or version except CentOS.

Comment: I have built and run 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Raspberry Pi 3).  It's been several months ago but do not remember any major problems.  Your error list looks like you have not installed log4cxx.  I basically followed the direction in the document for sub$100 which is apparently not supported for 2.0+ but the instructions were still helpful.

Comment: Redhawk-src-2.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.05-5 is working fine.

Comment: log4cxx was unable to install but log4cxx-dev was installed on Ubuntu 16.10 while I got the error. Except that I changed the gcc version from 6 to 4.8 with C++2011 support, but all this did not work for me. I also tried to change the xsd version from 4 to 3.3 but compiling of xsd failed at end